# A rule seems totally ignored in Kivy Language

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I just settled on Kivy/Python to develop an app, hence I'm learning Kivy language.
I kind of understand how the language works after watching the Crash Course Videos. However, I now get a behavior that I cannot comprehend with the following script I wrote:

**File `utils/sidebar.kv`**

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window

<NavButton>:
    size_hint: 1, 0.5
    color: 0,0,0,1
    background_color: (1,1,1,1)
    background_normal: ''


<SidebarWidget>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,1,1,1
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

    size_hint: 0.05, 0.5
    pos_hint: {"x": 0.95, "center_y": 0.5}

    NavButton:
        id: nav_home
        text: 'Home'
        pos_hint: {'y': 0.5}

    NavButton:
        id: nav_map
        text: 'Map'
        pos_hint: {'y': 0}
```

**File `map/map.kv`**

```
#:kivy 2.1.0
#:import sidebar utils.sidebar
#:include utils/sidebar.kv

<MapRootWidget>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgba: 0,1,0,1
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        SidebarWidget:
```

Note that `MapRootWidget` inherits `Screen`, and `SidebarWidget` inherits `Widget`. If need be, I can include the Python files. However, except for a few event callbacks and properties, there is not much touching the widgets geometry.
By running it, I obtain the following screen:
[image: NavButton are one bottom-left corner, their background color not changed]

The weirdest is that not even the background color of the `NavButton` is updated (I manually set it to white).

If you have any hints as to why it is not working, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks for your time

Edit: I just set the `NavButton`'s `background_normal` property to `''` and and changed the `background_color` to yellow. The color is correctly applied, so only the positioning is broken. (It was due to the default mode multiplying the default grey color with the background_color property)

Edit Bis: Absolute positioning works just fine. It is only the relative one using `pos_hint` that doesn't work. I can't grasp as to why.

Comment: What is a `SideBarWidget`?

Comment: `SibeBarWidget` simply inherits `Widget`, it has no new properties

Comment: That is your problem. A `Widget` is not designed to be a container, so it does not honor things like `pos_hint`. Change the base class of `SideBarWidget` to one of the `Layout` classes.

Comment: oh ok, I didn't notice since I'm used to api that use `Widget` as nodes and not only leaves. Thank you very much that worked.

Comment: Something is bugging me though. Isn't a Scatter also a Widget? Then, how comes in the official crash course videos, a Label is declared as a child of a Scatter, and everything seems to work in sync?

Comment: Everything in kivy is a widget, some implement methods to act as containers, some don't.